# HERE Maps API; before:destination constraint is ignored in findsequence request

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm using https://wse.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json

Here is my request parameters:

```
mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=2019-10-10T15:39:28+03:00
```

And here is the body:

```
destination4=4;38.792417,-77.30097;acc:th00:00:00+03:00|fr00:00:00+03:00;st:180
&destination5=5;38.792344,-77.299805;before:destination4;acc:th00:00:00+03:00|th19:00:00+03:00;st:180&start=user;38.776573,-77.275411&destination7=7;38.804577,-77.279514;before:destination5;acc:th00:00:00+03:00|fr00:00:00+03:00;st:180
```

That's what i have in the response:

> {"results":[{"waypoints":[{"id":"user","lat":38.776573,"lng":-77.275411,"sequence":0,"estimatedArrival":null,"estimatedDeparture":"2019-10-10T14:09:49+03:00","fulfilledConstraints":[]},{"id":"5","lat":38.792344,"lng":-77.299805,"sequence":1,"estimatedArrival":"2019-10-10T14:15:44+03:00","estimatedDeparture":"2019-10-10T14:18:44+03:00","fulfilledConstraints":["acc:th00:00:00+03:00|fr19:00:00+03:00;st:180","before:destination4"]},{"id":"4","lat":38.792417,"lng":-77.30097,"sequence":2,"estimatedArrival":"2019-10-10T14:19:21+03:00","estimatedDeparture":"2019-10-10T14:22:21+03:00","fulfilledConstraints":["acc:th00:00:00+03:00|fr00:00:00+03:00;st:180"]},{"id":"7","lat":38.804577,"lng":-77.279514,"sequence":3,"estimatedArrival":"2019-10-10T14:28:19+03:00","estimatedDeparture":null,"fulfilledConstraints":["acc:th00:00:00+03:00|fr00:00:00+03:00;st:180","before:destination5"]}],"distance":"7548","time":"1290","interconnections":[{"fromWaypoint":"user","toWaypoint":"5","distance":3626.0,"time":355.0,"rest":0.0,"waiting":0.0},{"fromWaypoint":"5","toWaypoint":"4","distance":191.0,"time":37.0,"rest":0.0,"waiting":0.0},{"fromWaypoint":"4","toWaypoint":"7","distance":3731.0,"time":358.0,"rest":0.0,"waiting":0.0}],"description":"Targeted best distance; without
>   traffic","timeBreakdown":{"driving":750,"service":540,"rest":0,"waiting":0}}],"errors":[],"processingTimeDesc":"78ms","responseCode":"200","warnings":null,"requestId":null}

As you can see i have **`before`** constraint in **destination7** and **destination5** but it's ignored. 
Am i doing smth wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have these waypoints: `start`, `destination4`, `destination5` and `destination7`  with constraints: `destination5` before `destination4` and `destination7` before `destination5`. Now you did not specify an `end` waypoint so the algorithm chose one of waypoints as the `end` waypoint for optimal results (in this case `destination7` was chosen as the end waypoint which then overrode the constraint). Please specify an `end` waypoint and the other constraints will be satisfied. Reference from documentation:

> destinationN: Intermediate destinations, at least one. If no end parameter is provided, one of these values is selected as end of the sequence.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/mobility-on-demand-toolkit/topics/determining-optimal-delivery-sequence.html

Comment: Nope. Adding `end` doesn't help. Request: `destination1=1;38.792859,-77.316802;before:destination7;st:180&start=user;38.776573,-77.275411&end=4;38.792417,-77.30097;st:180&destination7=7;38.804577,-77.279514;acc:sa00:00:00+03:00|su00:00:00+03:00;st:180`

Response:
https://pastebin.com/VMHyPPvG